# Recursive CTE to Oracle 10g R2

Tags: sql-server, oracle10g

I have the following code working in SQL Server 2008 but I now need to implement it in Oracle 10g R2 which doesn't appear to support recursive CTEs. Essentially, it groups the records into events for each PID where two records are considered to be the same event when the older record's END_DATE is within 90 days of the newest record's START_DATE (although there will be more conditions in the final implementation).

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1840b/3

```
    WITH C AS
    (
        SELECT PID, START_DATE, END_DATE AS EVENT_START, 1 AS EVENT, RN, END_DATE
        FROM SampleTable
        WHERE RN=1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT C.PID, R.START_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN R.START_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, -90, C.EVENT_START) THEN R.END_DATE ELSE C.EVENT_START END,
        CASE WHEN R.START_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, -90, C.EVENT_START) THEN C.EVENT + 1 ELSE C.EVENT END,
        R.RN,
        R.END_DATE
        FROM C INNER JOIN SampleTable R ON C.PID = R.PID and C.RN=R.RN-1
    )
```

Any solution should be ok as it will be run against a small (200,000 record) dataset one time, although I'd be interested to see if/how this could be done in SQL with START WITH...CONNECT BY.

Comment: The recursive query is quite easy actually: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b697/1 but I don't understand why you need a recursive query in the first place. Simply using `lag()` or `first_value()` to check for the "older rows" and "newest row" seems to be enough as there is no real hierarchy here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately the offset changes. When we start the event, we use the END_DATE of the that record for all subsequent START_DATE checks until one START_DATE is >90 days of the END_DATE. We call that a new event and then use it's END_DATE to compare the next subsequent START_DATES. In the case of your fiddle: the last two records with PID=123 should both have RN=3.